# How does readInt() work in Android?

Tags: java, android, stream, android-networking

I am very new to network programming.

I have the bellow source running in one Thread. From other thread I am closing `istream`, `ostream` and `socket`, but still no `IOException` is printed from below code. I am running this code on an Android phone. On some Android phones, the behavior is proper and printing `IOException`, on other phones it's not printing.

I really want to know how `readInt()` really works. What might be problem in some handsets its not printing IOException?

```
while(true){
try {
int readInt=istream.readInt();
}
catch(IOException e){
Log.i("Sample","IOException");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the source for readInt() to see what it really does. If you are trying to read beyond the end of the stream you should always get an EOFException.

If you are closing the thread from another thread. the VM should trigger a SocketClosedException, but it is possible some makes of Android phones don't honour this behaviour.

Comment: Not getting any exception, in the source posted above. What may be the reason?

Comment: I would check if all versions of Android phones are guaranteed to trigger an IOException when the stream is closed asynchronously. I suspect they are not.

Comment: Thanks for answers, found the solution at bellow link. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7933

Comment: It says its was closed Aug 2010, but it not clear if this only impacts a) older version of Android or b) some versions which might be relatively new.